# groovy "with" block usage query

Tags: groovy

I am trying to use the with block in Groovy to easily initalize my class, but I am getting the following error. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
MyXMLTemplate template = new MyXMLTemplate ().with {
    TxId = 'mnop'
    oapTxId = 'abcd'
}
```

The error I get is:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'abcd' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'org.example.MyXMLTemplate'
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:331)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:599)
```

I am using groovy 1.8.0

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to return the template itself from the `with` block:

```
MyXMLTemplate template = new MyXMLTemplate ().with {
    TxId = 'mnop'
    oapTxId = 'abcd'
    it
}
```

Comment: yes this works! The documentation does not have this though...:(

Comment: Which page of the documentation?  The main Groovy site is a wiki so can be changed to be correct :-)

Comment: I should have said "Javadoc". I have downloaded the source and I get this incomplete documentation on mouse hover.-> This is commonly used to simplify object creation, such as this example: def p = new Person().with { firstName = 'John' lastName = 'Doe' }

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't crash as it uses `def` for the `p` variable, but it does set `p` to the String `Doe` rather than a Person object...  Just [checked the docs for 1.8.2](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#with%28groovy.lang.Closure%29), and it does show having to return the `it` variable, so maybe it's something that got recently fixed?

Comment: Since Groovy 2.5 you can use the `tap()` method, so you don't need to return `it`; see https://dzone.com/articles/groovy-goodness-easy-object-creation-with-tap-meth

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to see what the problem is without seeing the definition of your class. I'll assume that `TxId` and `oapTxId` are both properties of the class.

I suspect your error is caused by `oapTxId` being of type `MyXMLTemplate`, and so not assignable from String.

Incidetally, as your `with` block is just initializing class properties, you could use the more idiomatic constructor and setters approach:

```
MyXmlTemplate template = new MyXMLTemplate(TxId: 'mnop', oapTxId : 'abcd')
```